# Escape Directory name coming in parenthesis

Tags: regex, ftp

I have issue in regex : Currently my PWD is like this

```
ftp> pwd
257 "(REPORT)TEXT ON ABC" is the current working directory.
ftp>
```

I used this in my properties like this for getting the SourceDir=/(REPORT)TEXT/

but I get this syntax erro as part of FTP :

```
FTP status: (Reply Received Message): 501-Error in LIST command parameters;  Scanning (REPORT)TEXT/..
501 Invalid File Name. Scanning .
```

Any idea on this ??

Comment: These `(` `)` are `parentheses`, not 'brackets'.

Comment: Yeah typo, how can I be using that in regex

Comment: Are you trying to capture just "(REPORT)TEXT" or "(REPORT)TEXT ON ABC"?

Comment: "(REPORT)TEXT ON ABC"

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you have parentheses that are literal then you would need to escape them like this:

```
\( ... \)
```

so your pattern would resemble something such as:

```
SourceDir=/\(REPORT\)TEXT.*/
```

if you don't escape them the pattern treats anything enclosed within them as a `capture group`.